# two divs stacked on top of each other -- link on bottom div not clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I want is this: On hover, a tile divides into two tiles and both tiles then work as individual links. Tiles should also change background color on hover.

To achieve this, I stacked two divs (`toptile` and `bottomtile`) on top of each other. On hover, `toptile` gets invisible and one can see `bottomtile`, which contains two divs that contain a hyperlink each.

```
<div class="tile">
    <div class="bottomtile">
        <div class="linktile"><a href="page1.php">ONE</a></div>
        <div class="linktile"><a href="page2.php">TWO</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="toptile">HELLO</div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.tile{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}

.bottomtile {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.toptile {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.toptile:hover {
    zoom: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
}

.linktile{
    height: 95px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.linktile:hover{
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Unfortunately, neither the background change in `.linktile:hover`, nor the hyperlinks work. I can see the words ONE and TWO but it's like I'm hovering an empty div. My assumption is that `toptile` acts like a transparent glass plane where I can look through to `bottomtile` but not actually reach it with my mouse.

I also tried `visibility: hidden` and `display: none` inside the `.toptile:hover` brackets but the problem stayed the same.

Is there a way to make toptile completely disappear on hover? Or another way to go round this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's because you declare this

```
.toptile:hover {
    zoom: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
}
```

because you're using `opacity: 0`, it just looks like it was no longer there, but the fact is the `.toptile` is still there, but invisible, so what you're really hovering is still the `.toptile` not the `.linktile`, that's why the `background` of `.linktile` never changed. what you need is to use `display: none`, and also the `.toptile` isn't the parent of `.bottomtile`, so when the `.toptile` dissapear, it won't hover on it anymore, so it'll reappear and disappear again, so you need to change the selector to `.tile:hover .toptile`, here's the changed `css` should be

```
.tile:hover .toptile {
    display: none;
}
```

here's the working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyojimaru/cwy7m774/)

Answer (score 0):

Use a `:hover` on `.tile` instead of `.toptile`

```
.tile:hover .toptile{
  /* your code to hide .toptile */
}
```

Your assumption is correct. It is on top of the `.bottomtile`, so you can't interact with `.bottomtile`. And if you'd completely let `.toptile` disappear, then your mouse wouldn't be hovering on it.

Answer (score 0):

Luud is getting you there. Here is a working pen of the idea, with some of the unneeded markup gone.

http://codepen.io/justindunham/pen/sCzcH

```
.bottomtile .linktile {
  opacity: 0;
}

.bottomtile:hover .linktile {
  opacity: 1;
}
```